# please solve this TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, class, typeerror

```
class traveler:
    def __init__(t,id,name,age,gender):
        t.id = id
        t.name = name
        t.age = age
        t.gender = gender

def myfunc(printinfo):
    print("Traveler ID is: " + printinfo.id)
    print("Traveler name is: " + printinfo.name)
    print("Traveler age is: " + printinfo.age)
    print("Traveler gender is: " + printinfo.gender)

t1 = traveler(1,"abc",20,"female")
t1.myfunc()
```

Comment: do `str(printinfo.age)` your age is a number. so can't be concatenated to string.

Comment: Better to use `f string` : `print(f"Traveler age is: {printinfo.age}")` instead of writing everything like that.

Comment: @Shamal_Shine : Why is this tagged with _shell_ ?

Comment: @user1934428 Beginners sometimes overdo the tags.  I removed `shell`, `class`, and 'python-idle` as irrelevant, and added `string` as that was the subject of the TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

Is a simple **TypeError**, you cannot concatenate different types with `+` inside a print function.

I'm sure that you could easily found the solution online.

Anyway, try to use this:

```
def myfunc(printinfo):
    print(f"Traveler ID is: {printinfo.id}")
    print(f"Traveler name is: {printinfo.name}")
    # etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use only `string` in a print statement

```
def myfunc(printinfo):
    print("Traveler ID is: " + str(printinfo.id))
    print("Traveler name is: " + str(printinfo.name))
    print("Traveler age is: " + str(printinfo.age))
    print("Traveler gender is: " + str(printinfo.gender))
```

Comment: Hope it helps.. i'm also enjoying the learning journey